# run android studio 2.3.3 kotlin project in android studio 3.0.1 after update

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

i have updated AS 2.3.3 to 3.0.1 using a patch .jar 
the update was successful however android studio keeps reminding me that i need to update Kotlin plugin. This Kotlin plugin was installed in the 2.3.3 version but think that android studio 3.0.1 doesn't require a Kotlin 
plugin.
So my question is what should i do in the old project so that it works fine in AS 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio 3 still requires the Kotlin plugin, the difference is that it's now bundled by default. To update the plugin, navigate to the Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates menu, and click "Check for updates" in the dialog that appears.